# How can remove Null value from f.select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have multiple dropdown when I select items. It also creates null value   How can I remove null values from this array?

```
 = f.select(:doc, file.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id]}, {}, id: "id-select2", class: "form-control", :multiple => true).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems there

Your collect is returning some nil elements(As Joseph said), in this case the name attribute is what it can be nil, so you can check for that on the collect

**Solution**(compact) [UPDATE]

```
f.select(:doc, file.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id] if a.name, include_hidden: false }.compact, {}, id: "id-select2", class: "form-control", :multiple => true)
```

Specify the include_blank option https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select

```
f.select(:doc, file.all.collect {|a| [a.name, a.id] if a.name }.compact, { include_blank: false, include_hidden: false }, id: "id-select2", class: "form-control", :multiple => true)
```

According to the docs for [select helper](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) I have found this gotcha

> The HTML specification says when multiple parameter passed to select
>   and all options got deselected web browsers do not send any value to
>   server. Unfortunately this introduces a gotcha: if an User model has
>   many roles and have role_ids accessor, and in the form that edits
>   roles of the user the user deselects all roles from role_ids multiple
>   select box, no role_ids parameter is sent. So, any mass-assignment
>   idiom like To prevent this the helper generates an auxiliary hidden
>   field before every multiple select. The hidden field has the same name
>   as multiple select and blank value.
>
> **Note**: The client either sends only the hidden field (representing the
>   deselected multiple select box), or both fields. This means that the
>   resulting array always contains a blank string.
>
> In case if you don't want the helper to generate this hidden field you
>   can specify include_hidden: false option.

So if you add the **include_hidden: false** option then you won't get the empty string on your multiple option when the data is sent to the controller.

Comment: You're not using `compact` correctly in this case, this won't work. `id` is a primary key, so it will never be `nil`, but `name` could be. This is like calling `[['a', 1], ['b', nil]].compact`. The entire array element must equal nil, not just a part of it.

Comment: @taylorthurlow you are right I updated the answer to check for the name attribute

Comment: @Elisamax I updated the answer to check for name attribute

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo unfourtunatlly  it is not working. that is weird :-(

Comment: @Elisamax can you put on your question the actual value that the collect is returning?

Comment: @Elisamax I updated the answer with a solution for the empty string on your multiple select using the include_hidden: false option

Comment: @JavierMenéndezRizo awesome. that worked thank you sooo much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `compact`. For example:

```rb
a = [nil, 2, 3, 4, 5]
without_nil = a.compact
# [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

using `compact!` will modify the original array whereas `compact` returns a new array.

Answer (score 0):

you can filter that in database query for example (I assume `id` is primary key and is not null):

```
file.where('name IS NOT NULL').load
```

Comment: @Elisamax What is your model name?

Comment: The model name is Folder

Comment: So if you have a field `name` you should do this:
`Folder.where('name IS NOT NULL').load`

Comment: Noting has changed:-(

Answer (score 0):

`compact` isn't working for you because you're likely calling it on the result of the `collect`. If you have an array like `[['a', 1], ['b', nil]]`, calling `compact` on it won't do anything because the `['b', nil]` is not `nil`. It only contains it. So you need to avoid loading the `File`s where `name == nil`.

You'd want something like this instead:

```
f.select(:doc, file.where('name IS NOT NULL').collect { |f| [f.name, f.id] }, {}, id: "id-select2", class: "form-control", multiple: true)
```

It might be more helpful if we knew exactly what `file` is.

Comment: file is the list of the files(all) I have in my dropdown.

Comment: I have tried and It didn't work. I am still getting [Null, 2,5]